# How do I sign a message with a newly created Near account in a 3rd party app?

Tags: nearprotocol

I'm setting up a new Near account, and I want to use its keys to sign a message in an app I'm building. How can I do this?

I used the wallet.nearprotocol.com page to create an account. Then, I used nearlib to connect to the testnet, and verify the account's balance and public keys.

But I couldn't find a way to add the account into the localStorage key store or otherwise access a method to sign a message. Nor could I find a wallet plugin or extension that would provide me access.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally the idea is that you never transfer given private key between 2 devices / security contexts.

So normally instead of getting private key out of wallet you just want to generate new key pair and request wallet to add public key.

https://github.com/nearprotocol/nearlib/blob/master/src.ts/wallet-account.ts provides relatively easy way to do it for webapp.
Note that it limits access to a give contract ID, so if you need unrestricted access you basically just need to omit `contractId`.

See examples at https://near.dev/ for `WalletAccount` usage.